# Sharepoint 2010 site column Localization

Tags: localization

I am creating a feature for the site columns where the DisplayName is localized using resource files deployed to 14\Resources for English and Spanish.

the issue is, when the feature is activated and the MUI language is changed to From English to Spanish the DisplayName is still in English.

after spend fare bit of time to get this to work, I got it to work when I removed the "`Overwrite='TRUE'`" from the site column definition.

in other words, the below caml **WORKS**

```
<Field ID="{5BC736BB-6B1C-485b-BB4B-3140C9E8E1C8}" 
         Name="xyzasdf171"  
         StaticName="xyzasdf171"
         SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
         Group="01" 
         DisplayName="$Resources:TestResource,SC_TestResources;" 
         Type="Text"  
           />
```

where as this does **NOT WORK**

```
<Field ID="{5BC736BB-6B1C-485b-BB4B-3140C9E8E1C8}" 
         Name="xyzasdf171"  
         StaticName="xyzasdf171"
         SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
         Group="01" 
         DisplayName="$Resources:TestResource,SC_TestResources;" 
         Type="Text" 
         Overwrite="TRUE"
           />
```

is there something I have missed or anyone came across similar kind of issue?

Regards

Praveen

Comment: This just saved my skin. Thanks! Another brilliant 'feature' that isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could not find any reason or solution for this online.

For the time being I have omitted  Overwrite="TRUE" attribute for site columns in the feature.

Praveen